# AutoCAD save file as a duplicate with the same name in another path: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Tags: lisp, autocad, autolisp

I am doing the following Lisp-based routine.

The original drawing is what is worked up to a say half way through the lisp on say pathA/drawing.dwg, the code then does a save as and duplicates the name into another path say pathB/drawing.dwg.

The rest of the code runs against the file while in the new path pathB/drawing.dwg because there are several things happening and being applied which makes it much different from pathA/drawing.dwg.

If I go back to open pathA/drawing.dwg, I get a 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object' error.

The code half way is pretty much

```
(setq pathBFileName (strcat "///pathb//" thisDrawingName ".dwg"))
(command "._saveas" "" pathBFileName (if (findfile pathBFileName) "y"))
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with AutoCAD registering that PathB/drawing.dwg was used and then when you the PathA/drawing.dwg it gets confused but I don't how to avoid this error or pass it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to avoid this. Just work on the open drawing to the end. And use the (command ".save" pathBFileName (if (findfile pathBFileName) "y"))

So anytime through you want to save just ensure you save to the right file. AutoCAD in this case will never open the actual PathB/drawing.dwg so then I don't have to see that reference problem again.